# Cant join tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel.
I need to join two tables, and i dont know what i am doing wrong.
When i check at telescope, my query isnt displayed.

This is the query i want to run

```
SELECT * FROM products join subcategories on products.subcategories_id = subcategories.id where subcategories.categories_id = 1
```

In my laravel controller i have

```
public function showCategoriesProducts(String $cat){
        $categories = Categories::all();
        $products = Products::join('subcategories', function($join) {
            $join->on('products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id');
         }) ;
        dd($products);
        return view('products.index',compact('products','categories'));
    }
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/categories/{categories_id}', 'ProductController@showCategoriesProducts')->name('categories.show');
```

My Products belong to subcategories and subcategories belong to Categories. I need to fetch products from category id.

Please Help
Thank You!

Comment: You're just creating the query builder right now. You need to add `->get()` to it, as well as your `where` clause.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For this (seemingly) simple use case you'd have a much easier time using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) along with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) so I am having difficulty understanding why a join is strictly necessary

Comment: yeah actually i was having a tough time with the relationships. Can you Please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the query, but not fetching records. Add `->get()` add the end of your query to make the request.

```php
$products = Products::join('subcategories', function($join) { 
    $join->on('products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id');
 })->get();
```

Comment: That is because you are using `$cat` inside an anonymous function. Call the function using the `use` keyword: `function ($join) use ($cat) {`